# How to set correct zoomScaleSensitivity for svgpanzoom library?

Tags: svgpanzoom

I am using svgpanzoom library ([link on github repository](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom)) in my project . I was setting some initial value:

```
var minValue = 0.8;
var maxValue = 6;
var numberOfSteps = 5;

instance.setMinZoom(minValue);    
instance.setMaxZoom(maxValue);
```

After that i was trying calculate and set new value for zoomScaleSensitivity:

```
var newValueForZoomScale = (maxValue - minValue) / numberOfSteps;
instance.setZoomScaleSensitivity(newValueForZoomScale);
```

Unfortunately , in this case i have 6 or 7 zoom's steps (depends of screen resolution). My question is how i can set correct value for zoomScaleSensitivity and always have only 5 (numberOfSteps) zoom's steps?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var newValueForZoomScale = (maxValue - minValue) / (numberOfSteps - 1);
```

That's because if you divide by N, you'll get N+1 steps like:

- if start is 1
- if end is 6
- divide by 5 (number of steps you want) and get `(6-1)/5 = 1` for step distance
- you'll get 6 steps: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

So you have to divide by 4, then you'll get `(6-1)/4 = 1.25` and 5 steps: 1, 2.25, 3.5, 4.75, 6